# How do I remove the JWT Authentication requirements from certain models? Django Rest API / Axios

Tags: django, authentication, axios, jwt

I have a few models, some of them just holds images and information I want to display on the screen (BEFORE the user logs in).

I followed a guide to setup my JWT authentication for users, and I created the other models myself.

I'm getting Unauthenticated messages when I try to do a .get() on my other models, which I do not want them to need to be authenticated. I want anyone to be able to login, and see that information.

What is a simple way that I can remove the authentication requirements from these models? I never set up any JWT for these models, so I am surprised the user model which has JWT is effecting these.

How can I send some information through my axios get request to say, "HEY THIS DOESN"T NEED TO BE AUTHENTICATED."  Like, a master key to get me through that requirement.

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpmqD.png)
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcR1M.png)
[example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoBTu.png)
[example 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrdjb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have function-based view use below code

from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

```
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def view_name(request):
    return Response("as you need")
```

if you have a class-based view then use below

```
class PublicEndPoint(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [] #disables authentication
    permission_classes = [] #disables permission
    
    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I needed.

permission_classes = []      fixed my issue.

I searched the web, but I didnt know the right keywords to find the answer. I tried expressing my issue on google every way I could think of... but couldn't find it. 

like your second option is how I did it. Ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify *permission classes* for APIView.

```
class DuckList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny] #this allows unauthenticated requests

    def get(self, request):
        ducks = Duck.objects.all()
    ...
    ...
    ...
```